# I need to add part of audio from one file to another

Tags: linux, bash, audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add the fist 15 seconds from file1.wav to end of file2.wav with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @FlashThunder, Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can create a `list.txt` of files with `inpoint` and `outpoint`, something like this:

```
file file2.wav
file file1.wav
inpoint 00:00:00.000
outpoint 00:00:15.000
```

And run:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.wav
```

Comment: If i clearly understand you creating new file output.wav. Is it wright?

Comment: @dim yes, it creates new file that merges the ones from the list with given directives about timestamps under each file (first has no directive, as you wanted it to be complete)